# Preencher inputs <text> após marcar <checkbox> e limpar ao desmarcar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ao marcar o chekbox todos os campos devem ser preenchidos com a palavra anônimo e ao desmarcar ele limpa os campos.

Meu html:

```html
<form>
Deseja anonimato?
    <input type="checkbox" id="anonimo">
    
    <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="seu nome">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="seu email">
    <input type="text" id="telefone" placeholder="seu telefone">
</form>
```

Comment: há algumas formas de se fazer isso: via for nos campos, aplicar valor diretamente pelo ID, adicionar uma propriedade pra aplicar o valor por esse parametro,...

Comment: Pelo ID já seria de bom tamanho. Obrigado pelo feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só mais uma forma de se fazer:

```js
$(function() {

    var check = $('#anonimo');
    
    check.on('click', function() {
        if(check.prop('checked') == true) {
          $('#nome,#email,#telefone').val('anônimo');
        } else if(check.prop('checked') == false) {
          $('#nome,#email,#telefone').val('');
        } 
    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
Deseja anonimato?
    <input type="checkbox" id="anonimo">
    
    <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="seu nome">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="seu email">
    <input type="text" id="telefone" placeholder="seu telefone">
</form>
```

Comment: Sua implementação foi a mais adequada pra mim, Obrigado!

Comment: Legal João, abraço!

Answer (score 5):

Um exemplo baseando em `ID`. Ao clicar no `checkbox`, ele executa uma função que verifica se está selecionado o `checkbox`, caso verdadeiro, insere "Anônimo" nos `input`, caso falso, insere vazio:

```js
function verificarCheckBox() {
    var check = document.getElementById("anonimo");
    
    if (check.checked){ 
       document.getElementById("nome").value = "Anônimo";
       document.getElementById("email").value = "Anônimo";
       document.getElementById("telefone").value = "Anônimo";
    }  else {
       document.getElementById("nome").value = "";
       document.getElementById("email").value = "";
       document.getElementById("telefone").value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
Deseja anonimato?
    <input type="checkbox" id="anonimo" onClick="verificarCheckBox()">
    <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="seu nome">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="seu email">
    <input type="text" id="telefone" placeholder="seu telefone">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Segue uma sugestão:

```
<form>
Deseja anonimato?
    <input type="checkbox" id="anonimo">

    <div id="containerInput">
      <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="seu nome">
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="seu email">
      <input type="text" id="telefone" placeholder="seu telefone">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$('#anonimo').click(function () {
    var texto = this.checked ? 'anonimo' : '';

    $('div[id="containerInput"]').find('input:text').each(function (i, obj) {
    $(obj).val(texto);
  });
});
</script>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ofdzwksm/

ou então, de forma simples só com JS e pelo ID como você disse:

```
<script>
function setaCampos(checado)
{
    var texto = checado ? 'anonimo' : '';

  document.getElementById('nome').value = texto;
  document.getElementById('email').value = texto;
  document.getElementById('telefone').value = texto;
}
</script>

<form>
Deseja anonimato?

    <input type="checkbox" id="anonimo" onchange="setaCampos(this.checked)">


      <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="seu nome">
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="seu email">
      <input type="text" id="telefone" placeholder="seu telefone">

</form>
```

Comment: Excelente mestre Jedi, a implementação com id foi mais util pois tenho outros campos como rg, cpf, cidade, endereço etc. Dessa maneira posso adicionar mais linhas em `var texto`. Muito obrigado!'

Comment: blza ;) sempre melhor deixar da forma mais generica possivel, assim seu codigo fica mais limpo

Answer (score 2):

Forma um pouco parecida com a do aa_sp porém mais simplificada:

```js
$("#anonimo").on("change", function(){
   $("form :text").val( this.checked ? "anônimo" : "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
Deseja anonimato?
    <input type="checkbox" id="anonimo">
    
    <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="seu nome">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="seu email">
    <input type="text" id="telefone" placeholder="seu telefone">
</form>
```

O seletor `:type` vai buscar tudo que for `type="text"`. Mas você pode usar types próprios para cada tipo de input para facilitar a entrada em dispositivos móveis. No caso do email, `type="email"`; telefone, `type="tel"`...

Neste caso, você pode usar o seletor `input` já que o jQuery não reconhece os seletores `:email` ou `:tel`:

```js
$("#anonimo").on("change", function(){
   $("form input").not(this).val( this.checked ? "anônimo" : "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
Deseja anonimato?
    <input type="checkbox" id="anonimo">
    
    <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="seu nome">
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="seu email">
    <input type="tel" id="telefone" placeholder="seu telefone">
</form>
```

O `.not(this)` é para ignorar o checkbox.

Outra forma é adicionando um prefixo comum aos id's dos campos, assim um seletor mais genérico pode ser usado:

```js
$("#anonimo").on("change", function(){
   $("[id^=user_]").val( this.checked ? "anônimo" : "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
Deseja anonimato?
    <input type="checkbox" id="anonimo">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="user_nome" placeholder="seu nome">
    </div>
    <input type="email" id="user_email" placeholder="seu email">
    <input type="tel" id="user_telefone" placeholder="seu telefone">
</form>
```

O seletor `[id^=user_]` irá selecionar todos os campos com id's que começam com `user_`.

### Com JavaScript puro

O seletor é o mesmo, só muda a construção:

```js
document.querySelector("#anonimo").onchange = function(){
   var campos = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=user_]");
   for(var x=0; x < campos.length; x++){
      campos[x].value = this.checked ? "anônimo" : "";
   }
}
```

```html
<form>
Deseja anonimato?
    <input type="checkbox" id="anonimo">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="user_nome" placeholder="seu nome">
    </div>
    <input type="email" id="user_email" placeholder="seu email">
    <input type="tel" id="user_telefone" placeholder="seu telefone">
</form>
```

Comment: Pode fazer a seleção direta tb :  `$("form :text")` e `$("form input")` . +1, boa resposta

Comment: Verdade, fica até mais simples. Me acostumei com essa sintaxe e esqueço as vezes que da forma que vc sugeriu é mais simples. Valeu!

Comment: Pô tio, 4 opções? Não dá para dar +4 ups só um mesmo rs;

Answer (score -1):

Fala Pessoal, eu segui as orientações aqui mas no meu caso eu tenho uma tabela com classes bootstrap, e o código javascript só funciona quando eu retiro a classe bootstrap. No caso do meu input checkbox, class="flat".

Comment: aqui é um espaço para respostas, use o espaço dos comentários para dicas ou no seu caso, que imagino ser um pergunta, crie uma pergunta com seu problema!